# Static vs Cache in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, caching, singleton

I am considering two patterns in my asp.net application where I would like to reduce overhead of a code execution by either static methods or using asp.net cache. They are as follows.

1. Static method

   ```
   Private Shared _transforms As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of System.Type, MyObject)()
   Private Shared Function Load(theType As System.Type) As MyObject
   Dim lockAquired As Boolean
   If Not _transforms.ContainsKey(theType) Then
       Try
           lockAquired = Monitor.TryEnter(_synchInstanceLock, LOCK_TIME_OUT)
            '...DO MY MEMORY INTENSIVE TASK HERE
           _transforms.Add(theType, doc)
       Catch ex As Exception
           Throw (ex)
       Finally
           If lockAquired = True Then
               Monitor.Exit(_synchInstanceLock)
           End If
       End Try
   End If
   Return _transforms(theType)
   ```

   End Function
2. ASP.NET caching , Note: Cache is just a wrapper for ASP.NET Application[""] Cache

   ```
   Private Function Load(theTypeAs System.Type) As MyObject
   Dim doc As MyObject = Nothing
   Dim lockAquired As Boolean
   Try
       lockAquired = Monitor.TryEnter(_synchInstanceLock, LOCK_TIME_OUT)
       Dim key As String = GenerateCacheKey(GetType(MyObject), theType.Name)
       Dim cacheData As MyObject = TryCast(Cache(key), MyObject)
       If cacheData Is Nothing Then
       '...DO MY MEMORY INTENSIVE TASK HERE
           Cache.Insert(key, doc)
       Else
           doc = TryCast(cacheData, MyObject)
       End If
   Catch ex As Exception
       Throw (ex)
   Finally
       If lockAquired = True Then
           Monitor.Exit(_synchInstanceLock)
       End If
   End Try
   Return doc
   ```

   End Function

Its for .NET 3.5

Could someone please advise which is better in terms of performance and thread safety?

Thanks

Comment: Just a critique on your try/catch/finally.  You are making it difficult to retain information about the original exception's origin.  It would be best to remove the catch code entirely and make your code into a simple try/finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version uses a `Dictionary`, which isn't thread-safe, and attempts to use synchronization to make the access thread-safe.  As it stands, you update the dictionary even if the lock wasn't acquired, so it isn't thread-safe.

You'd be better using a `ConcurrentDictionary` and getting rid of the locking code.

If I understand correctly, your second version is using the `HttpApplicationState` object, which is not the same as "caching" - which normally uses the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` object.  In either case, the dictionary is thread-safe and your locking code is redundant.

Of course, none of this says anything about thread-safety of accessing members of the object you retrieve from the dictionary.  If it's immutable, you'll be OK, otherwise you may need additional synchronization.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention that its for .NET 3.5 so cant use ConccurrentDictionary.